# How do I stop a perform selector when i delete a row from a table view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, performselector

I have an app that sends UDP messages when you click a button. I then give them 10 seconds to change their mind on whether they want to send the message or not. I use:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(sendMessage:) withObject:_dataString afterDelay:10.0f];
```

here is the button pressed code:

```
- (IBAction)RecordButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSString *Str = display.text;
    NSDateFormatter *clockFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [clockFormat setDateFormat:@"kk:mm:ss:SSS"];

    NSString *myT = [clockFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    _dataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0, %@, %@, \"%@\"", Str, Str, myT];

    [self performSelector:@selector(sendMessage:) withObject:_dataString afterDelay:10.0f];

    [_tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)sendMessage:(NSString *)message {
    NSData *data = [message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [udpSocket sendData:data toHost:ipSaved port:portSaved withTimeout:-1.0 tag:0];
}
```

I have a table view that is editable and when I delete a table view cell and the data in it I want to stop what ever data that is in the cell from sending if it is within the 10 second time limit.

I know there is  `[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:yourTarget selector:aSelector object: anArgument];` , but I cannot figure out how to make that stop the message from sending after I delete the table view cell and the core data in it.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [tableView beginUpdates];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(sendMessage:) object:_dataString];

        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.getRaceRecords objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSError *error;
        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"did not save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you remove the code you posted originally for the `commitEditingStyle:` method? Show how you have tried to call `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:...`.

Comment: I agree with @rmaddy, the code snippet you posted along the question was useful.

Comment: You seem to be using an instance variable `_dataString` to hold the message that will be used with `cancelPrevious...`.  The problem is that the string will get overwritten by the next call to `RecordButton`. So if you queue multiple messages, deleting any row will cancel the last message queued.

Comment: Why not just configure an `NSTimer` to call your `sendMessage:` method after 10 seconds have elapsed? If the user changes their mind before the ten seconds are up, you can just invalidate the timer.

Answer (score 0):

(Let's assume that everything's running on the main thread, so that there aren't any synchronization issues.) Here's what I would do:

- assign a unique sequence number to each message
- add the sequence number to an `NSSet` when the message is created
- remove the sequence number from the NSSet when either

  a) the message is cancelled, or
     b) the message is sent
- in the `sendMessage` method, verify that the sequence number is in
  the `NSSet` before sending the message

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at NSOperationQueue and creating a subclass of NSOperation. NSOperations can be cancelled - you have to write some code to do it, but it's reasonably easy. And NSOperations are *meant* to be cancelled.